# "Will be recommended for publication in IEEE Xplore." What does it mean?

Tags: publications, conference, ieee

"All accepted papers will be published in the conference proceedings and will be recommended for publication in IEEE Xplore." The quote was taken from a conference site. Does this mean that accepted paper will definitely be published in IEEE Xplore once accepted, or does that mean that there is a chance only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an established IEEE-sponsored conference, then I would expect that it means they will definitely be published in IEEE Xplore.  Typically, the IEEE simply transforms the conference proceedings directly into an IEEE Xplore collection, and that *is* the official archival proceedings of the conference.

The only publications that typically do *not* make this transition are those which are not presented at the conference (e.g., the authors don't show up), which the IEEE does not generally allow to be published as part of the final proceedings.

Comment: Your latter statement contradicts "All accepted papers will be published" in the quote of the question... (I suspect that your explanation is more accurate, and that there is some fine print somewhere regarding revocation of acceptance in case of no-show -- but the original rule really then ought to say "All accepted and presented papers" for clarity)

Comment: Hey, as you've said, it's right. They transform the conference proceedings into IEEE Xplore collection. Just checked their last year work of that. Thanks for the clear information.

Comment: @BenVoigt I agree that the conference organizers do not appear to have presented things in the most clear manner.

Answer (score 1):

I recommmend you to be careful. There are a lot of spam or predatory conferences, and some claim to be, or claim they will be, indexed in some more or less "prestigious" collections. They use that to lure authors.

You could check whether the conference was indexed last year (and the year before). You can give the website, some here may know.

Comment: Hey, I checked it out and as you've said, the conference was indexed in IEEE Xplore last year but not the year before last year. They are even specified in the conference search list of IEEE.

Comment: My opinion is that IEEE is unlikely to withdraw the recently accepted conference, but noone can be sure. And IEEE is not a certificate of quality, even if it looks nice on a resume. Personal advices to avoid weak conferences: [Scam/Spam conferences](http://www.laurent-duval.eu/siva-conferences-spam-scam.html )

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it. Hopefully it's a good and legit one :)

Comment: Very personal, and depends a lot on participants :) The real question is: how important for you is that the conference is indexed in IEEE XPlore

Comment: So far, pretty important I'd say. Considering this is my first paper to be published. Plus "it looks nice on a resume" as you specified it :)

Comment: If you dare to say the name (and delete the comment afterward), if it is in my field, I can give you a feedback (for what it's worth)